# C# socket listener for non-IP low level traffic with non-conventional EtherType

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with a protocol where I have to listen for frames like this:

[image: GOOSE Frames]

The frames are not IP frames and the source and destination addresses are OUI specific MAC addresses. I can be certain the destination MAC address will always be a multicast MAC address (where the first bit of the first octet is `1`).

These frames are "published" or "broadcast" and I'd like to write a socket listener for them without using a third party library, like SharpPcap or Pcap.Net.

What I basically want to do is receive these frames with this weird EtherType `0x88b8`.

I heard elsewhere that if I didn't want to use third party libraries then I would have to use a modified NDIS driver. I'm willing to do that.

But I'm wondering if it needs to be that needlessly complicated. If the destination MAC of these frames is a multicast address, I'm wondering if there something I'm missing that I can use to my advantage. I wonder if these frames could be floating around the Class D Multicast IP Addresses and I just have to listen on `224.0.0.0`.

I see a lot of questions about sending raw Ethernet packets, but none about receiving them, which is apparently much easier. So my ultimate question is, is there a way to do this just with the .NET Framework or Core?

I have been trying something like this,

```
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unspecified, SocketType.Unknown, ProtocolType.Unspecified);
```

and trying to narrow it down from there, but even that doesn't work.

Comment: If the traffic isn't IP traffic then you'll never see it on 224.0.0.0 (or any IP address) because the IP address field doesn't exist in all protocols.  A multi-cast MAC address is a network layer below the IP concept of multicast.

Answer (score 0):

Possible socket options:

AddressFamily SocketType ProtocolType

```
Unspecified Stream Icmp
Unspecified Stream Ggp
Unspecified Stream Tcp
Unspecified Dgram Udp
Unspecified Raw Icmp
Unspecified Raw IcmpV6
Unix Stream Unspecified
InterNetwork Stream Tcp
InterNetwork Stream Unspecified
InterNetwork Dgram Unspecified
InterNetwork Dgram Udp
InterNetwork Raw Icmp
InterNetwork Raw IcmpV6
InterNetworkV6 Stream Unspecified
InterNetworkV6 Stream Tcp
InterNetworkV6 Dgram Unspecified
InterNetworkV6 Dgram Udp
InterNetworkV6 Raw Icmp
InterNetworkV6 Raw IcmpV6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).